# Python tornado use inheritance with parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, tornado

I have a base handler class like this:

```
class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        module = self.request.uri.split('/')[1].split('?')[0]
```

this get method handler consists of 100 lines of code, As you can see module is acquired from url. in some cases I just need to change module and I don't want to completely rewrite get method.
Is there any way to Inherit this method and change module?

Answer (score 0):

As your `get` accepts `**kwargs`, you can add this line:

```
module = kwargs.pop("module") or self.request.uri.split('/')[1].split('?')[0]
```

So you can inherit this method in subclass and change module:

```
module = ...
super(Subclass, self).get(id, *args, module=module, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Where to put this code? in my inherited class get method?